# How to send E-mail with voting options using outlook in c#

Tags: c#, vba, outlook

I try to send a yes or no question via outlook in c#. I want to explain what I want.

1- Send an e-mail and the mail must include Yes or No button and when the receiver vote yes or no  I've to collect his/her answer and update status in my db. I know how to update the status in my db, just I want to know how to send yes or no question via outlook using c#. Sorry for my english.

```
Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mail.To = "abc@xyz.com";
mail.Subject = "this is subject";
mail.Body = "this is body";
mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
((Outlook.MailItem)mail).Send();
MessageBox.Show("your mail sent");
```

This code works fine to send and e-mail but I don't know how to add yes or no button in my mail.

Comment: Is the YES/NO function a built in feature of Outlook? If not, you have to create a link to a server you provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692221/creating-outlook-voting-button-and-tracking-response-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Which platform you using? windows form, mvc or asp.net

Comment: I believe that ```mail.Body``` accepts html? If it does you can create simple buttons with the ```button``` tag and add js to send their vote to a remote server

Comment: I read that question and there is no answer

Comment: I'm using windows form

Comment: Yes, this question is not a duplicate. Can you try making an HTML body that includes a yes no button which sends the output to a remote server. ```<button onClick="sendToServer("YES");">Yes</button> ``` ```<button onClick="sendToServer("NO");">No</button>``` you need to write the server according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MailItem.VotingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingoptions?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1363)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to set up voting options. To read the response you need to use [MailItem.VotingResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingresponse) property. This property is usually set to one of the delimited values returned by the `VotingOptions` property on a reply to the original message. For example:

```
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    private void OrderPizza()
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Application.CreateItem(
            Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        mail.VotingOptions = “Cheese; Mushroom; Sausage; Combo; Veg Combo;”

        mail.Subject = “Pizza Order”;
        mail.Display(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1

Create a valid HTML body which includes the buttons for "yes" "no"

I gotta say this from the beginning I do not have any information about the outlook version of this but I can give you with Gmail SMTP;

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("TestBlahBlah@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("your_mail_adress@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;     // <-- This here is improtant
        mail.Body = "Vote for x y z<br/> <button>YES</button> <button>NO</button>";
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("TestBlahBlah@gmail.com", "your_l0ng&pRobably_SeCuRe_pwd_157");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;// <-- This is also important

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

## Step 2

I don't know javascript so I cant help but what you need to do is:

#### Create a server

Make a server that runs on node.js or you can also do it from c# with sockets and etc.

#### Send information to this server from your buttons

```
mail.Body = "<script>  var someNiceVar = goodString'; </script>"+
            "<script> function sendData(Server server, Data data) {sendDataToServer("YES")} </script>"+
            " Vote for yourQuestionOrSomething "
            " <button onClick="sendData(Server, 'YES')">YES</button>"+
            " <button onClick="sendData(Server, 'NO')">NO</button>"+
            " "
```

Disclaimer: This is not real code :)

## Step 3

Record the data you receive from the mails.

## Important Note

One thing very important about the gmail version is that gmail doesnt let this from default so to send mails from your account to some other account using a third party app, you need to enable trust less secure apps from

`Manage your google account > Security > Less Secure App Access > Trust less secure apps > On`

Again, I don't know the outlook version of this but I would be careful.